# Plotting data from a cell to a scatter plot MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, plot, cell

I'm currently trying to teach myself some MATLAB plot functions and I'm wondering if its possible to plot directly from a matrix to a scatter plot.

I start of with a 1x9 cell like this:

```
x = ['Dog' [3] [5] 'Cat' [6] [1] 'Goldfish' [7] [8]]
```

And then created a 3 x 3 cell out of it like this:

```
x = reshape(x.',3,[]).';
```

to yield

```
x = 
    'Dog' [3] [5]
    'Cat' [6] [1]
    'Goldfish' [7] [8]
```

What I now want to do is create a scatter plot out of this data and use the first column as labels on the plot. So for example the point (3, 5) would have label "Dog"

Not too sure how to do this but I think the legend function might work to create the labels.

Are there any ways to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this using the [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function, which creates text at the location you specify. So, if you plotted your data like so:

```
plot(x(:,2),x(:,3),'x');
```

you could get labels like so:

```
text(x(:,2),x(:,3),x(:,1));
```

You may have to add a small constant so that the labels don't overlap the points. You may have to fiddle a little to get this value to your liking.

```
c = 0.1;
text(x(:,2) + c,x(:,3),x(:,1));
```